# Irvine PROC causes errors

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I hope this is a simple problem. I'm taking assembly language using Kip Irvine's files. The problem is when I try to use the examples i'm getting things like

```
The system cannot find the file C:\Irvine\Examples\Project_sample\Debug\ASM_Proj
ect.exe.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Obviously, the error is because the file doesn't exist. I've tried with visual studio 10 and 12 with both versions of his files with no luck. No amount of googling has helped me either. Please someone shed some light on this. Is the file supposed to be created when the project is built? What is going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured this out. Watching the debug folder carefully during build process I realized the file IS getting created by visual studio. It was also magically getting deleted within a second or two of it's creation.

So what was causing this?

My antivirus program (avast) was doing it. Disabling it made the program work fine. I sure hope this helps someone else, I was about ready to give up.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons...

- Did you assemble the source file ?
- Did you link the resulting object files from the assembler ?
- Are you familiar with the relationship between source -> object -> EXE ?
- Are you familiar with the relationship between Masm, Link, and `ml.exe` ?

Your tags say `Assembly` and `masm`. Are you using Masm to assemble the source ? Or are you doing this within Visual Studio ? That is a significant difference. (They both work, but are different animals.)

If this is your first exposure to assembly and Masm, Let me encourage you to stick with this. Masm can do some incredibly neat stuff; despite its drop in popularity of recent years. At the start, you are going to hit these "idiot walls" over and over again. Believe me, it's worth it.

Comment: the assmebly masm think, I don't know visual studio is building it. Assembling the source? you mean building it? yes. im not familiar with any of that. I like assembly language, just wish this wasn't so difficult to get working on my computer, might have to drop the class if I can't do my homework.